# Plotly: Shape lines passing in the middle of the cells in a heatmap

Tags: python, plotly, line, heatmap

I am drawing a heatmap using `plotly` in python. I want to draw a rectangle around certain areas and I'm doing it as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

layout_heatmap = go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(title='Years'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Years'),
    )

ff_fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(x=all_years, y=all_years, z=heatmap, showscale=True,
                                         colorscale='Viridis',)
fig = go.FigureWidget(ff_fig)
fig.layout = layout_heatmap
fig.layout.annotations = ff_fig.layout.annotations
fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
  
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              x0=1960, y0=1960, x1=1966, y1=1966,
              line=dict(color="red"),
              )
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              x0=1967, y0=1967, x1=1970, y1=1970,
              line=dict(color="red"),
              )
fig.show()
```

The output is being as follows:
[image]

I dont want the rectangle to pass through the cells, I want an effect like this but its not working:
[image]

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you in the end?

Comment: @vestland Hi, unfortunately I was not able to make it work, I'm pretty sure your code is correct but I don't know why on my workspace its not working. Probably a version issue

Comment: OK,and thank you for the swift feedback! Any chance you would consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer? If a better solution comes along, this can always be undone.

Comment: @vestland thank you as well for your detailed feedback and code, it helped a lot indeed.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to check back when you've had the chance to test it on updated versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option seems to be to:

**1. change axis types to categorical:**

```
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.update_yaxes(type='category')
```

**2. place your shapes by their position instead of value:**

```
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              x0=-0.5, y0=1.5, x1=3.5, y1=5.5,
              line=dict(color="blue", width = 4),
              )

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              x0=3.5, y0=-0.5, x1=5.5, y1=1.5,
              line=dict(color="green", width = 4),
              )
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code with a built-in plotly dataset

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.stocks()#.tail(50)
df = df.drop(['date'], axis = 1)
dfc = df.corr()
z = dfc.values.tolist()

# change each element of z to type string for annotations
# z_text = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in z]
z_text = [[str(round(y, 1)) for y in x] for x in z]
# df.columns =['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
df.columns =[1960, 1962, 1964, 1966, 1968, 1970]
# df.columns =['y1960', 'y1962', 'y1964', 'y1966', 'y1968', 'y1970']

# set up figure 
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x=list(df.columns),
                                     y=list(df.columns),
                                     annotation_text=z_text, colorscale='agsunset')

# add custom xaxis title
fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color="black",size=14),
                        x=0.5,
                        y=-0.15,
                        showarrow=False,
                        text="",
                        xref="paper",
                        yref="paper"))

# add custom yaxis title
fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color="black",size=14),
                        x=-0.35,
                        y=0.5,
                        showarrow=False,
                        text="",
                        textangle=-90,
                        xref="paper",
                        yref="paper"))

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              x0=-0.5, y0=1.5, x1=3.5, y1=5.5,
              line=dict(color="blue", width = 4),
              )

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              x0=3.5, y0=-0.5, x1=5.5, y1=1.5,
              line=dict(color="green", width = 4),
              )


# adjust margins to make room for yaxis title
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, l=200))

# add colorbar
fig['data'][0]['showscale'] = True
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.update_yaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you @vestland, But I am still facing issues. I ran the same code you pasted but the plot is empty and shrinked and it has no values at all. What might be the issue ?

Comment: @Perl Then its probably a version issue. But I will double check on my end

Comment: yes the same code you pasted. I also think its a version thing. Please let me know in case of any updates. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Perl I double-checked with a fresh kernel. Code runs fine on my end. Plotly version is `'4.12.0'`.

Comment: @hans and Perl: The categorical xaxis seems to be the problem. Try to replace the years with a list of actual strings like ['year 1966', 'year 1968'...]

Comment: @hans Strange. Are you absolutely certain that `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')` and 
`fig.update_yaxes(type='category')` were included in your previous runs?

Comment: @vestland It works if the years are replaced with a list of actual strings, i.e. 'year 1966', just like you said.

Comment: @hans I see, but `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')` should have the very same effect (like it has on my end), so I'm still a bit puzzled.